# Know which elements don't exist inside an IN clause in sql

Tags: sql, db2, sql-in

I got a query like this

```
Select * from tablename where field1 in (a,b,c,d);
```

I want to know if there is a way where if an element is not found the the dbms return all the fields of this element with a null

example

```
+-------+-------+-------+
|field_1|field_2|field_3|
+-------+-------+-------+
|a      |1      |4      |
+-------+-------+-------+
|b      |null   |null   |
+-------+-------+-------+
|c      |4      |5      |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Then you don't actually need to filter your table, just do `SELECT CASE WHEN field_1 NOT IN (..) THEN NULL ELSE field_1 END AS field_1, ...
FROM tablename`

Comment: What is it about row 2 that determines showing nulls? a, b, & c are in your list.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify what database software you are using, but you could create a temp table, add your desired values, and left join to the source table:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (field1 VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('a')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('b')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('c')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('d')

SELECT t1.field1, t2.field2, t2.fields
FROM #temp t1
LEFT JOIN tablename t2 ON t1.field1 = t2.field1
```

Another way would be a UNION:

```
Select * from tablename where field1 in (a,b,c,d)
UNION 
SELECT 'a', null, null, null WHERE 'a' NOT IN (select field1 FROM tablename)
UNION 
SELECT 'b', null, null, null WHERE 'b' NOT IN (select field1 FROM tablename)
UNION 
SELECT 'c', null, null, null WHERE 'c' NOT IN (select field1 FROM tablename)
UNION 
SELECT 'd', null, null, null WHERE 'd' NOT IN (select field1 FROM tablename)
```

(I'm assuming that the values `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`, `'d'` are not present in an existing table - otherwise just `LEFT JOIN` that table like the temp table example does.)

Comment: Hello, i can't use any temporary tables and i'm using DB2